# Free registrations still asking for payment info

Tags: cividiscount, stripe

We are using CiviDiscount and when a discount is 100%, either with a code or automatic discount, and the submissions cannot be completed with a "Payment Info Missing" error.    Using civi 5.2.2 and Stripe payment plugin.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found out there is a fork of the Stripe payment plugin for Civi 5.X.  This fixed my issue.  Can be found here:

https://github.com/mattwire/com.drastikbydesign.stripe

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug with the Stripe payment processor but unfortunately there’s no one assigned for the fix as yet –

https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/215

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in CiviDiscount.

They have an active issues list here https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/issues.

If your issue is not already reported, I would suggest doing so.

Comment: FYI, this was an issue with Stripe payment plugin, not CiviDiscount.